# Menu has both "Discord" and "Discord (Env)". Why 2 versions, and how do I remove the latter?

Tags: snap, deb

I downloaded Discord from discord.com *(chose a `.deb` file)*, and installing ended up giving me both "Discord" and "Discord (Env)". **Is there a way to get rid of "Discord (Env)"?** Snap *(which I suppose installs Discord when the `.deb` is double clicked)* only shows 1 "discord".

*As requested by N0rbert:*

`dpkg - l | grep discord` returns:

```
ii  discord                                     0.0.16
amd64        Chat for Communities and Friends
```

`snap list | grep discord` returns:

```
discord    0.0.16           130    latest/stable    snapcrafters     -
```

`find ~ -name '*discord*.desktop' 2> /dev/null` returns:

```
/home/user/.local/share/applications/discord_discord.desktop
```

Comment: Please run the following commands - `dpkg -l | grep discord` and `snap list | grep discord`, `find ~ -name '*discord*.desktop' 2> /dev/null` and add their output to the question.

Comment: @N0rbert done.`

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove Discord which is installed as Snap with

```
sudo snap remove discord
```

and then run `update-menus` .

Then use deb-packaged Discord as it was planned.

Comment: I probably didn't tell my question well, because the way to solve my issue turned out to be doing the opposite of what you describe. Instead of removing the snap version and using the deb, I removed the deb and used the snap version. It seems Discord provides an odd installer on the website.